# Mongoose how to select certain object in embedded array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I had been searching around and still not able to find the correct answer.

Basically I have the below data model in mongodb

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "565db83bcd7bef020b1bdae8"
},
"userId": {
    "$oid": "5653a3267827f178214918fc"
},
"targetUser": [
    {
        "userId": {
            "$oid": "564663a5c0aefc151625b5e2"
        },
        "status": "Approved",
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "565db83bcd7bef020b1bdaea"
        }
    },
    {
        "userId": {
            "$oid": "564548249bb75c600ff94cdd"
        },
        "status": "Sent",
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "565db884cd7bef020b1bdaed"
        }
    }
]
},
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "565db884cd7bef020b1bdaec"
},
"userId": {
    "$oid": "564548249bb75c600ff94cdd"
},
"targetUser": [
    {
        "userId": {
            "$oid": "5653a3267827f178214918fc"
        },
        "status": "Pending",
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "565db884cd7bef020b1bdaee"
        }
    }
]
}
```

How can I only return the follow data???

```
{
"userId": {
    "$oid": "5653a3267827f178214918fc"
},
"targetUser": [
    {
        "userId": {
            "$oid": "564663a5c0aefc151625b5e2"
        },
        "status": "Approved",
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "565db83bcd7bef020b1bdaea"
        }
    },
}
```

I had use the below code, but the result is return null

```
Connection.aggregate([
    {$match:{userId:'5653a3267827f178214918fc'}},
    {$unwind:'$targetUser'},
    {$match:{'targetUser.status':'Approved'}},
    {$group:{
        _id:'$_id',
        targetUser:{
            $push:{
                status:'$targetUser.status'
            }
        }
    }}
],function(err,connections){
    console.log(connections);
    console.log(err);
})
```

Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you don't need to aggregate, a simple [`find`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) with a projection parameter will return what you need.

```
Connection.findOne({
    userId: new ObjectId("5653a3267827f178214918fc")
}).select({
    targetUser: {
        $elemMatch: { status: "Approved" }
    }
}).exec(callback);
```

But if you have more fields than `userId` and `targetUser`, you'll need to add them in the second parameter like this

```
Connection.findOne({
    userId: new ObjectId("5653a3267827f178214918fc")
}).select({
    targetUser: {
        $elemMatch: { status: "Approved" }
    },
    oneMoreField: 1,
    anotherField: 1
}).exec(callback);
```

Comment: Hello ShanShan, I try to do the following but still not populate anything,     `Connection.find(
        {
            userId: new ObjectId("5653a3267827f178214918fc")
        },
        {
            targetUser: {
                $elemMatch: { status: "Approved" }
            }
        }
    ).exec(function(err,connections){
            console.log(connections)
            console.log(err)
        });`

Comment: What `Connection` stands for? I assumed it was the collection you were querying but I guess not. Can you edit your question and add the code about `Connection` (remove any personal information)?

Comment: It's related to mongoose's syntaxe, I'm editing my answer now.